# R regular expression replace :75% -> 0.75

Tags: regex, r

Surely a naive question but I'm in R and I have the expression

```
v <- "gastrula:75%"
```

that I want to replace with `"gastrula0.75"`

I tried things like :

```
v <- sub("\\.(\\d+)%","0.\\1",v)
v <- sub("[:punct:](\\d)\\1+[:punct:]","0.\\1",v)
```

But I didn't find anything that worked.

Comment: What about `v <- "gastrula:5%"`? Should that come back as `gastrula.5` or `gastrula.05`? Or `v <- "gastrula:200%"`? Are you trying to replace the percent with it's decimal value?

Comment: @MrFlick judging by their example I'd say that `gastrula:5%` should be replaced with just `gastrula0.05%`, no? Don't see your confusion on that one. `200%` should be probably replaced with just `2` I'd guess

Comment: @DavidArenburg That would be my guess as well, but then it's not going to be fun to do the math in pure regular expressions without knowing if there is a very limited set of transformations that needs to happen.

Comment: @MrFlick : yes gastrula:5% should be replaced by gastrula0.05 and all percentages should be <100% so I would not have more than 2 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possibility:

```
v <- "gastrula:75%"
str <- unlist(strsplit(v,":"))
paste0(str[1], as.numeric(gsub("%","",str[2]))/100)
```

Answer (score 7):

You may try

```
 sub('^([^:]+):(\\d+).*', '\\10.\\2', v)
 #[1] "gastrula0.75"
```

Or may be

```
 library(gsubfn)
 gsubfn(':(\\d+)%', ~as.numeric(x)/100, v)
 #[1] "gastrula0.75"

 v1 <- c(v, 'gastrula:5%')
 gsubfn(':(\\d+)%', ~as.numeric(x)/100, v1)
 #[1] "gastrula0.75" "gastrula0.05"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> v <- "gastrula:75%"
> gsub("^(.*)\\:(.*)%", "\\10.\\2", v)
[1] "gastrula0.75"
```